# How to test error case in Angular service testing?

Tags: angular, testing, observable, angular-services

I have a service in which there are some observable methods. In some conditions, the method throws an error.
like this below:

```
 calculateMyItem(a:number): Observable<state> {
     if (a<1){
       throw new Error('Please input valid number');
     } 

    return of({item:'item1',status:'success'});
 }
```

In service.spec I want to test this method of service. Subscribe does not work since the error is thrown just I call the method and before subscribing it happened.

for example if I use this `service.calculateMyItem(0).subscribe({error=>console.log('error')})`
but I got the error in this part `service.calculateMyItem(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT, you can use the `toThrowError()` matcher from Jasmine:

`expect(() => {calculateMyItem(0)}).toThrowError();`

-- Old answer below --

You can wrap the call in a try catch and check if you reach the catch block:

```
let errorThrown = false;

try {
  calculateMyItem(0);
} catch (e) {
  errorThrown = true;
}

expect(errorThrown).toBeTrue();
```

Comment: I do not want to use the try-catch block in the test. It would not be correct to use a try-catch block in test cases.

Comment: Then what about the `toThrowError()` matcher, that I wrote about in the top of the question? Btw, I do not think that it would be bad to use try/catch if that matcher did not exist. This is what also the matcher does under the hood, see [source code here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/d0e1bd96fb2ba50097a3c1594f484c643ee85bf2/src/core/matchers/toThrowError.js#L32)